# How to change the colour of all points on z-axis of matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to cycle colours for all different points on the z-axis. I have read other forums and the advice would be generally to spilt up the z axis, but this would be rather inefficient as I'm trying to run a code with a few thousand different points for the z axis. Is there a way to do so such as through itertools or constructing any loops? I have tried these methods but unfortunately I haven't had much progress in them.

Thank you in advance!

```
colours = "r", "g", "b"
ax.scatter(range(len(sequence_containing_x_vals)), sequence_containing_y_vals, sequence_containing_z_vals, c = colors)
ax.set(xticks=range(len(sequence_containing_x_vals)), xticklabels=sequence_containing_x_vals)
```

Comment: You should edit your question to be a [mcve] that includes some example data. What do you expect the outcome to be? The points cycle through the colours red, green, and blue?

Comment: The easiest and fastest way would be to use numpy arrays, and numpy array slicing (e.g. `y_arr[0::3]` to select every 3rd starting with the first). Also note that thousands of different x labels will never fit into a plot.